# Setting std::map items as itemdata of CListBox

Tags: c++, mfc, stdmap, clistbox

I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903789/storing-stdmap-iteration-object-as-itemdata-in-cgridctrl) but the context of this new question is different.

## Background

I have this variable: `PublisherMap m_mapPublishers;`

The definition of `PublisherMap` is:

```
using PublisherMap = std::map<CString, S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX>;
```

## The code

I have this method that reads the map and populates a `CListBox`:

```
bool CChristianLifeMinistryPersonalCopiesDlg::InitPublishersGrid()
{
    try
    {
        m_lbPublishers.ResetContent();

        for (auto & mapPublisher : m_mapPublishers)
        {
            bool bInclude = false;

            if (m_iDisplayMode == DISPLAY_EVERYONE)
                bInclude = true;
            else if (m_iDisplayMode == DISPLAY_BROTHER && mapPublisher.second.eGender == GENDER_MALE)
                bInclude = true;
            else if (m_iDisplayMode == DISPLAY_SISTER && mapPublisher.second.eGender == GENDER_FEMALE)
                bInclude = true;

            if (bInclude && m_bLimitDisplay)
            {
                CString strTemp;
                if (!m_mapSSAssignedPublishers.Lookup(mapPublisher.first, strTemp))
                    bInclude = FALSE;
            }

            if (bInclude)
            {
                int i = m_lbPublishers.AddString(mapPublisher.first);
                m_lbPublishers.SetItemData(i, MAKEWPARAM(mapPublisher.second.eGender, mapPublisher.second.eAppointed));

            }
        }
    }
    catch (_com_error e)
    {
        LPCTSTR szError = e.ErrorMessage();
        AfxMessageBox(szError);
        return false;
    }
    catch (CException* e)
    {
        e->Delete();
        AfxMessageBox(_T("CException"));
        return false;
    }

    m_iSelectMode = SELECT_NONE;
    UpdateData(FALSE);

    return true;
}
```

Notice that I use item data:

```
m_lbPublishers.SetItemData(i, 
    MAKEWPARAM(mapPublisher.second.eGender, mapPublisher.second.eAppointed));
```

It works absolutely fine. If I was using a `CPtrArray` I would have assigned the actual structure object pointers against each entry in the list box.

## The question

I don't know the mechanics of `std::map` enough. Is there any safe way to directly associate each entry from the map (`mapPublisher`) against each list box entry so that I can later access it?

I realise I could take the text of the list box entry and then find it in the map and get it that way. But if there is a more direct way to tie the two together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map` is specified as an associative container that never moves existing elements, see [[associative.reqmts]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts#9):

> The `insert` and `emplace` members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the `erase` members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.

In practice it's often implemented as a red-black tree.

So it is safe to keep pointers to existing elements, as long as their lifetime exceeds the lifetime of the pointers.

Note you will lose that guarantee if you switch to `std::unordered_map` (a hash map).

---

To set:

```
    m_lbPublishers.SetItemDataPtr(i, &mapPublisher.second);
```

To retrieve:

```
    auto psEntry = (S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX*)m_lbPublishers.GetItemDataPtr(i);
```

`CListBox::GetItemDataPtr()` returns `void*` so a cast is required.

Comment: This is a difficult one! I find both of your answers informative. You both provide information that it would be great to combine into one answer.

Comment: That is a good enhancement to the answer. This might also be added to your answer for a more modern cast alternative `static_cast<S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX*>(m_lbPublishers.GetItemDataPtr(i));`

Comment: [CListBox::SetItemDataPtr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistbox-class#setitemdataptr) is better suited here. `SetItemData` would require a cast. Both set the same field in the item data, but the former takes a pointer type, whereas the latter takes a `DWORD_PTR`.

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant. updated. `static_cast` vs C-style cast is another discussion altogether, which I'd like to leave at that :-) Either one will work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the node of the map isn't destroyed/deleted you can pass a pointer to the mapped datatype directly to the `CListBox::SetItemDataPtr`.

So in your case accessing the `S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX` and using a pointer using `&mapPublisher.second` is OK.

This is guaranteed by the rules for the STL

Comment: Thanks. And related to this, what would be the more modern approach to casting the pointer back. At the moment I now have: `S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX *psEntry =  (S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX*)m_lbPublishers.GetItemDataPtr(i);`.

Comment: I never us the old C casts. I would use static_cast<S_DEMO_ENTRY_EX*>(m_lbPublishers.GetItemDataPtr(i)); But to be more typesafe you may derive your own class for the listbox and use your own accessor functions, that use the correct type. For the compiler it is all the same at the end.

Comment: Great. I have an issue now because I have been provide two answers and they both supply different information and pertains to the answer. I want to accept both of your answers!